# Select results from 2 tables if particular match in the third one

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
t1
--------------
userID
userEmail
userName
userType

t2
--------------
businessID
businessUserID

t3
--------------
recordID
recordBusinessID
action (ENUM: pending, open, closed)
```

I need to retrieve records if results found in t3 ONLY has records with with action = 'pending'.

```
SELECT
   t2.businessID,
   t1.userEmail,
   t1.userName
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t1.userID = t2.businessUserID)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t3.recordBusinessID = t2.businessID)
WHERE userType = 'active'
AND t3.action = 'pending'
t3.action != 'open'
t3.action != 'closed'
```

It seems like I should be getting results, because my current t3 is empty,  but I don't. What am I missing?

t3 can have results but I only need to match if t3.action is nothing but 'pending'.

Comment: `AND t3.action is null` gets result, I think. But your where clause, i'm not sure, selects smthg

Comment: @splash58 I actually need to select results if there's a match in t3, but it ONLY has to be 'pending'.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: `LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t3.recordBusinessID = t2.businessUserID)`. From the name of your fields, I would expect the join to be `t3.recordBusinessID = t2.businessID`.

Comment: @JeffKilbride -- good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing Null with any value returns Null even if you check  `not equal to`. So to test that there is no corresponding value or it is not equal to something, do so:

```
where ... and (t3.action is null or t3.action != 'pending')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`? If you only want records that match `t3.action = 'pending'`, a normal join will work. I would rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT
   t2.businessID,
   t1.userEmail,
   t1.userName
FROM t1, t2, t3
WHERE t1.userID = t2.businessUserID
AND t2.businessID = t3.recordBusinessID
AND t1.userType = 'active'
AND t3.action = 'pending'
```

For this to work, you will need data in all three tables. If `t3` is empty, you will get no results.

A `LEFT JOIN` is typically used to find ALL the rows in the left tables that match the `WHERE` clause, plus any data in the right tables that matches the `ON` clause. From the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING
>   part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for
>   the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that
>   have  no counterpart in another table.

If this doesn't work for you, please clarify your question and post some example data from your `t1, t2, and t3` tables and I will try to help.